# MediaRouteButton not showing with RemoteDisplay Application ID

Tags: android, chromecast

I am developping a chromecast application for android, implementing  RemoteDisplay using the sdk v2.

My `MediaRouteButton` nevers shows on my menu for discovery using an application ID I created for `RemoteDisplay` applications on the cast developer console but the button appears if I use `CastMediaControlIntent.DEFAULT_MEDIA_RECEIVER_APPLICATION_ID` as ID.

Here is ***my Activity***:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


public final static String ID = "99FB28D7";

MediaRouter mediaRouter;
MediaRouteSelector  mediaRouteSelector;
private CastDevice selectedDevice;

private MyMediaRouterCallback routerCallback = new MyMediaRouterCallback();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    this.mediaRouter = MediaRouter.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
    this.mediaRouteSelector = new MediaRouteSelector.Builder()
            .addControlCategory(CastMediaControlIntent.categoryForCast(ID)).build();

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    MenuItem mediaRouteMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.media_route_menu_item);
    MediaRouteActionProvider mediaRouteActionProvider =
            (MediaRouteActionProvider) MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(mediaRouteMenuItem);
    mediaRouteActionProvider.setRouteSelector(this.mediaRouteSelector);
    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    this.mediaRouter.addCallback(this.mediaRouteSelector, routerCallback, MediaRouter.CALLBACK_FLAG_REQUEST_DISCOVERY);
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    this.mediaRouter.removeCallback(this.routerCallback);
    super.onStop();
}

private class MyMediaRouterCallback extends MediaRouter.Callback {

    @Override
    public void onRouteSelected(MediaRouter router, MediaRouter.RouteInfo info) {
        selectedDevice = CastDevice.getFromBundle(info.getExtras());
    }

    @Override
    public void onRouteUnselected(MediaRouter router, MediaRouter.RouteInfo info) {
        selectedDevice = null;
    }
}
}
```

My ***main.xml*** menu:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
    android:id="@+id/media_route_menu_item"
    android:title="@string/media_route_menu_title"
    app:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.
    app.MediaRouteActionProvider"
    app:showAsAction="always"/>
</menu>
```

I am testing on ***Android Marshmallow*** running `GooglePlayServices 11.7.` I also tried downgrading `GooglePlayServices` to  `10.2`, but it is still not working.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few weeks, I tried my code again and everything was working fine. I don't know what happened but I found this issue someone opened:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/69470206 .

It might be related.